# Python, parsing thru dict and change data type

Tags: json, mongodb, datetime, python-3.x, pymongo

I am pretty new to Python & MongoDB. I am trying to fetch all documents from mongoDB in to a dictionary first and then iterate them one by one to some business logic.

```
dest_docs = [doc for doc in dest_collection.find({key: {'$in':_ids}})]
dest_docs_dict = {doc[key]: doc for doc in dest_docs}
......
for key in _ids:
   source_doc = source_docs_dict.get(key, None)
   dest_doc = dest_docs_dict.get(key, None)
```

I would need the Documents to be represent in clean JSON format but i see the python is representing date values like this "datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 31, 4, 0)".

My business logic component requires clean JSON format as input, I tried using JSON.DUMPS() menthod but that was unable to parse this type of object.

Is there any work around to convert these date time objects into string representation for JSON to work? Please share your thoughts..i deeply appreciate any help. thanks!

```
SAMPLE JSON-DICT{
   'prod_doc_key': 'StaplesCACAS/en-CA/1-CA/CL169792/12870', 
   'metadata': {
       'store_id': 6051, 
       'partnumber': '12870'
    },  
    'promotions': [{
        'promomessage': {
            'enddate': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 31, 4, 0), 
            'name': 'Buy More, Save More', 
            'type_name': 'promo offer expires', 
            'startdate': datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 1, 4, 0), 
            'typeid': 35, 
            'text': 'Offer Expires on 08/31/2020'
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON doesn't have a specific date format and standard python's json encoder library doesn't force conversion of non standard data.

Anyway you could you the [default](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) parameter of dump(s) method to give it way to convert non standard fields: the dummiest way is the following:

```
import datetime, json
X = {'data': datetime.datetime.now(), 'number':10}
try:
    print json.dumps(X)
except TypeError:
    print "Sorry, it doesn't works"
print json.dumps(X, default=lambda y:str(y))
```

Of course investigating the type would be better, and using datetime.strftime could be useful to obtain the preferred date format.